# get details of user through github api gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github-api

i am using the "github_api" gem in my project to get user data through github

and hear is my controller got this task

```
class SocialController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def authorize
    address = github.authorize_url redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/social/callback'
    redirect_to address
  end

  def callback
    puts params
    authorization_code = params[:code]
    access_token = github.get_token authorization_code
    access_token.token   
    puts Github::Client::Repos.new.list
  end

  private

  def github
    @github ||= Github.new client_id: 'f11661f7a9ba943', client_secret: '08aa35ed997b162de257c'
  end
end
```

and i am calling it through this link in my views

```
<%=link_to "gitouath", controller: "social", action: "authorize" %>
```

by this i am able to authorize the github profile but i need some other details like his name, profile and projects but i am not able to figure it out, please tell me if there is a way to get those details

Comment: I would advise you remove and regenerate the Client ID and Client Secret should they not actually be fake values...

Comment: I have original values don't worry about them

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `github_api` gem, so I'll give a generic answer: the [API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/) are your friends and contain everything you need to know, it's a good idea to get familiar with reading them.

To get you started, the user name and profile information is available via the [`GET /user` endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-the-authenticated-user) and the list of repositories (I assume this is what you mean by "projects") can be found via the [`GET /user/repos` endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories).